# Checking if model state is valid against a value in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown list in my MVC application which is a required field in my form.

I have created and filled out my list like so:

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ServiceName,
                    new SelectList(
                        new List<Object>
                        {
                            new { value = "Empty", text = "Select..."},
                            new { value = "Service Name 1", text = "Service Name 1"},
                            new { value = "Service Name 1", text = "Service Name 2"},
                            new { value = "Service Name 1", text = "Service Name 3"},
                            new { value = "Service Name 1", text = "Service Name 4"}
                        },
                            "value",
                            "text",
                            0), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I'm needing my form to return back a message that tells the user that they need to select an option from this menu is they do no select anything. My service name has  `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Service Name must be selected")]` above it in my Model class.

It looks like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Service Name must be selected")]
public string ServiceName { get; set; }
```

However I have no idea how I can check against this value. So far I've tried the following:

```
if(newMember.getProperty("serviceManager").Value == "0")
{
   ModelState.IsValid = false;
}
```

But this doesn't work. I've tried a few variations of the above but they haven't worked either. Im currently googling to find an answer but I'm not having much luck.

Could someone please explain to me how I can achieve what I want to achieve?

Edit

Just updated my code to show the new test I just completed but it still didn't return back an error telling me Service must be selected when I submit an empty form.

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to invalid if the first option (with value = 0) is selected?

Comment: yes that is what I would like to do

Comment: Is your `ServiceName` property `int` or `Nullable<int>` and does it have `[Required]` attribute?

Comment: Currently it is a string as the values are going to change to something else one I know what they are. They are 0-4 purely for convenience at the moment. Yes it has the Required tags above it.

Comment: I'll post an answer based generating the `SelectList` in the controller (doing it in he view like that is not good practice)

Comment: Thank you. I'm very new to MVC.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Very debatable - I prefer to keep display-agnostic collections in my view models and generate a SelectList in the view wherever possible, but it all depends on how much logic there is involved in creating the actual SelectList itself (and what is involved in that logic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the overload of `DropDownListFor()` that renders an option label, and make you `ServiceName` property nullable with `[Required]` attribute. The issue with you existing `SelectList` is that you include the first option which has a value ("Empty") which is a valid string so it passes validation.

Model

```
[Required]
public string ServiceName { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
List<string> services = new List<string>() { "Service Name 1", "Service Name 2", "Service Name 3", "Service Name 4" };
ViewBag.Services = new SelectList(services);
return View(yourModel);
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ServiceName, (SelectList)ViewBag.Services, "--Please Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessagFor(x => x.ServiceName)
```

Note the `SelectList` does not contain an element for "--Please Select--". The 3rd parameter of `DropDownListFor()` adds a label option which has no value `<option value>--Please Select--</option>` which if selected will result in the property being invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You have your getProperty to get serviceManager but you view is binding to ServiceName.

Try changing it to...

```
if(newMember.getProperty("ServiceName").Value == "0")
```

OR

I dont have visual studio available at the minute so code might not be exact.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ServiceName,
                new SelectList(
                    new List<Object>
                    {
                        new { value = 1, text = "Service Name 1"},
                        new { value = 2, text = "Service Name 2"},
                        new { value = 3, text = "Service Name 3"},
                        new { value = 4, text = "Service Name 4"}
                    },
                        "value",
                        "text",
                        0), "Select...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

and if you have [Required] on your ServiceName in your ViewModel then in your controller you will be able to do ModelState.IsValid e.g.

```
if(ModelState.IsValid){
    // Do code here if it is valid
}else{
    return View(viewModel)
}
```